# Database design with PostgreSQL: implementing foreign and primary keys

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design

I'm completely new to databases, and I'd like some insight on how to design a PostgreSQL database with this schema I have in mind. I'm not sure how to implement primary/foreign keys and relations in this case to achieve what I want.

I have created a a large table of customers, with the following information:

```
CUSTOMER
- unique ID
- review of the product ("positive", "negative")
- full name
```

Now, each CUSTOMER needs to have a PRODUCT table (which can be empty) and which contains a list of products:

```
PRODUCT
- product ID
```

and each product in this PRODUCTS table needs to be associated with an ITEMS table (which can also be empty), which contains a list of items.

```
ITEMS
- item ID
```

In the end, I want to be able to order individual items from the ITEMS table based on how "positive" or "negative" the customer reviews were. How do I implement foreign and primary keys in this case to be able to design this effectively?

Any insight would be much appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: What is the relationship between items and products?

Comment: Each product ID is associated with many item IDs @LaurenzAlbe

Answer (score 1):

You'd have a table for each items, products and customers (the latter without the review).

Then you have a table for reviews:

```
CREATE TABLE review (
   customer_id bigint REFERENCES customer NOT NULL,
   product_id  bigint REFERENCES product  NOT NULL,
   is_positive boolean NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (product_id, customer_id)
);

/* this is needed if customers ever get deleted */
CREATE INDEX ON review (customer_id);
```

Comment: . I would add a mention of this being a classic example of Many-to-Many relationship. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)

Comment: Thank you both, I think both the answer and this resource pointed me in the right direction.